# Why have content site outside your domain

Tags: internet, web, cdn

Why do sites deliver downloads or static content from outside their main domain name ?

Obviously if you are using akamai or some 3rd party CDN to deliver your static content, but why would you put your downloads / images in some other domain that looks like a typo squatter?

Apart from user confusion (is microsoftupdates.hub.com legit?) it leads to issues like Dell forgetting to renew `www.dellbackupandrecoverycloudstorage.com` its hard coded site for OS image restores which expired and was replaced by malware.

In the early days it was presumably easier to have all your static images come from a completely separate path - but I'm sure the load balancers at mcirosoft.com can handle that these days

Comment: At times, getting a site on the main domain for big corporations means a massive amount of bureaucracy, review, and involvement of difficult-to-work-with departments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when using 3rd party CDN, the DNS allows using subdomains for hosting different services at different locations / service providers. Even the administration of a subdomain can be delegated somewhere else using new `NS` records. There's no technical limitations that would force using random side domains.

Therefore, these decisions are made for some other reasons: marketing, policy, stupidity... you name it. Frankly, your example with Dell clearly falls into the category of stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

Our friends over at Webmasters.SE have a  reason: a cookie-less domain for performance. [What is the advantage to hosting static resources on a separate domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/25087)

http://sstatic.net/  has a page explaining that it serves this purpose for the Stack Exchange network.

The more you, the user, notice interact with this other domain, the less it is well integrated. There are plenty of one-off marketing sites and other purpose built domains. Hopefully they don't get neglected.

Comment: So for static icons there is a sensible reason. For downloads it is just corporate stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

Separation of duties.

When you want to send content to a CDN, be it internal or external, you'll probably be delegating some of your naming to a GSLB or other DNS based load balancing scheme.  Delegating something to a third party is always risky, and I know my company for example, never allows a third party to send email as our domain, the risks are too high. All it would take is for them to mess up, and we get blacklisted.  No thank you.  This is probably being done for very similar reasons.